# Five dimensional matrix manipulation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have made the following changes to the code but still get the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error on the line where the "if statement" is called and I am for looping the "h" starting from 2:25. I still have net figured out how I can use an element from the previous dimension in the current dimension equation expression

```
  number_of_days = 3;
number_of_hours = 24*number_of_days;
number_panels = 1:5;


for idx_number_panels = 1:length(number_panels) % range of PV panel units examined

for number_turbines = 0:1 % range of wind turbine units examined

    for number_batteries = 1:2 % range of battery units examined


        for h=2:25 %# hours
               battery_capacity(:,:,:,1,1) = max_battery_capacity*number_batteries;

            for d = 1:number_of_days %# which day

                n = h + 24*(d-1);



                if   (max_battery_capacity*number_batteries) - (battery_capacity(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h-1,d)*number_batteries) >0

                    storage_availability(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h,d) =  (max_battery_capacity*number_batteries) - (battery_capacity(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h-1,d)) ;

                else


                    storage_availability(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h,d) = 0;


                end
```

Comment: I still seem to get the same error when i use "h" instead of where I have "h-1"

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this just by hours.

```
for h = 1:24
    battery_capacity(1) = initial_battery_capacity*number_batteries

    if hourly_total_RES(h) > hourly_annual_demand(n), % battery charging
        battery_capacity(h) = battery_capacity(h-1);
    else
        battery_capacity(h) = battery_capacity(h-1);
    end
end
```

First off, the both sides of the if statement are the same as written. I assume that your actual code does some sort of work with the previous data. If not, that's a problem.

It also might make the code a little easier to think about if you switch the order of the day and hour loops. To me, looking through all the hours of one day at a time makes better sense than looking at the first hour of each day, then the second hour of each day...

As for the indexing, one definite error is that you index `battery_capacity(h-1)` on the first iteration of the loop. That is, when `h` is 1, you define `battery_capacity(1)` and then try to look at `battery_capacity(0)`, which is probably what's throwing the error.

To fix this, you could check to see if `h == 1`, but I think a more elegant way would be to loop through `h = 2:24` and set `battery_capacity(1)` before entering that loop. See if this code works:

```
for d = 1:number_of_days
    battery_capacity(1) = initial_battery_capacity*number_batteries
    for h = 2:24
        if hourly_total_RES(h) > hourly_annual_demand(n), % battery charging
            battery_capacity(h) = battery_capacity(h-1);
        else
            battery_capacity(h) = battery_capacity(h-1);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: thank Andrew I have tried your suggestions but I am still getting the same error on the if statement "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
"

Comment: Andrew, I think I need to keep the day dimension as I need to be able to access other parameters on a daily basis. If I remove the day dimension will I be able to access 24 hour slots for 365 days. i.e 1:24, 25:48 etc etc?

Comment: @user643469 Yes, you can index arrays in Matlab by `array(25:48)`. You could even write a helper function to make that conversion.

Comment: Hi Andrew I have made some changes to my original code due to the output variables I have had to change. I think I have to keep the hour and day as two separate dimensions as it makes life easier later on. What I really need help with is to figure out the code that will allow me to take the element from the "hour" dimension of the previous matrix. (i.e back to the h-1 argument!) and use it in the "current matrix" throughout the loop. Can we continue this discussion  on the comment section of my original post? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the last two dimensions store the hour and day respectively. So to set the value for first day at hour=1 (I assume this means midnight start of day):

```
battery_capacity(:,:,:,1,1) = 2;    %# 2kWh
```

This will set the value `2` for all "panels" and all "turbines" and all "batteries".

I assume you have the matrix already pre-allocated somewhere in your code.

---

For what its worth, I think you have a typo where you first mention `battery_capacity` in the code (there is a missing `h` parameter)

Comment: yes I think you have understood my question thank you. I still get the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." on the line " battery_capacity(idx_number_panels , number_turbines + 1,number_batteries, h,d) =." at the if statement.

Comment: I think the error I am getting is due to the h-1 format I have used. However since the battery_capacity at hour 1 of day 1 is set to equal 2 as you have mentioned in your answer, I don't see why this is the case. What I am trying to achieve is to kick start the battery_capacity at equal 2 and then use the equation I have which changes depending on the "if statement" to continue for the remaining hours